# Set width to be the same as another control

Tags: xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin.Forms application, I have an `Image` and a `Label`:

```
<Image x:Name="myImg"/>
<Label x:Name="myLabel"/>
```

I want the width of the `Image` to be the same as the width of the `Label` (the text of the `Label` is determined at runtime). How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this by binding the Image's WidthRequest to the Label's Width property.

```
<Image x:Name="myImg" WidthRequest="{Binding Source={x:Reference myLabel}, Path=Width}" />
<Label x:Name="myLabel" />
```

Comment: Maybe try binding to Path=WidthRequest?

Comment: Actually `Path=Width` worked, I just had to call `OnPropertyChanged()` in the code behind whenever I change the text or set the image.